# How to make NetworkManager add a DNS server at the top of /etc/resolv.conf?

Tags: centos, networkmanager

Right now, my /etc/resolv.conf looks like this:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 10.165.246.33
nameserver 192.135.82.60
nameserver 10.165.74.2
```

The first two nameservers are automatically configured through DHCP; the last one is the one I added manually, in NetworkManager. It's also the most important one, since it resolves our internal domain names (e.g. `build-server-17.our-company-domain.com`).

The trouble is, NetworkManager adds it to the *bottom* of `/etc/resolv.conf`, so when accessing an intranet URL, my browser tries to resolve it using the first two servers, and it takes ages.

How do I make NetworkManager add the manually-configured DNS server *before* the automatically-configured ones?

Comment: In general, all DNS servers in your resolv.conf should return the same results. Having mixed servers in there is a recipe for intermittent failures and lots of pain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see which system to address specifically, but if yours is using `resolvconf`, try the following as root (`su -` or `sudo -i`):

```
echo 'nameserver 10.165.74.2' >> /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
resolvconf -u
```

There is a warning in that file which states that manual changes will be overwritten; but, in context, the message applies to `/etc/resolv.conf`, not `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`.

This should place the desired name server first in the list. Of course, if this works on your operating system, then 10.165.74.2 can be removed from NetworkManager.

The local resolver, `dnsmasq`, is also an excellent path forward. Using `dnsmasq`, one can utilize much more control over DNS and DHCP. For example, in this scenario, `dnsmasq` can query a specific name server based on a specified domain name with its `server` option. See a snippet from `dnsmasq.conf` that might pertain to your objective below.

```
# Add other name servers here, with domain specs if they are for
# non-public domains.
server=/our-company-domain.com/10.165.74.2
```

**Update**

Thanks for mentioning the operating system. On CentOS 7, there are many methods. In the GUI, click Applications > System Tools > Settings > Network. Select a connection to configure.

[image: CentOS 7 NetworkManager - Configure Connection]

Turn off Automatic DNS and supply name servers. Apply the configuration.

[image: CentOS 7 NetworkManager - Apply Static DNS Settings]

Next time NetworkManager starts that connection, it writes the custom values. (While testing, I turned the network off and then on again because I had two network connections.)

According to [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Installing_NetworkManager.html#sec-Interacting_with_NetworkManager),

> 1. A simple curses-based text user interface (TUI) for NetworkManager, nmtui, is available.
> 2. A command-line tool, nmcli, is provided to allow users and scripts to interact with NetworkManager. Note that nmcli can be used on GUI-less systems like servers to control all aspects of NetworkManager. It is on an equal footing with the GUI tools.

In particular, the `nmcli` [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Using_the_NetworkManager_Command_Line_Tool_nmcli.html) looked very good.

Comment: Sorry, it's CentOS, which doesn't have a `resolvconf` package. `dnsmasq` seems like a good solution, though.

Answer (score 14):

I accidentally created a duplicate question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385888/how-to-reorder-etc-resolv-conf-at-load-time).  The answer is there, but essentially, you need to create:

```
/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
```

if it doesn't already exist, and add:

```
prepend domain-name-servers [ip address of server];
```

Don't forget the semicolon at the end!

After that, simply rebooting automagically moved the 'nameserver [ip address of server]' line in the '/etc/resolv.conf' up to the top!

Comment: Marvelous ! That's the backend used by NetworkManager, and the only way to get this working with all wifi connections (not static). thanks !

Comment: Modifying dhclient doesn't make changes on Rocky8, it uses NetworkManager

Answer (score 0):

There is another way, no need to turn off NetworkManager.service.
Just set ifcfg-idevice:

```
PEERDNS=no
DNS1=10.165.74.2
DNS2=OTHERDNS
DOMAIN=DEMO.COM
```

You don't need to set /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf settings, like:

```
[main]
dns=none
```