# Use the DHCP provided DNS nameserver as a fallback in networkmanager

Tags: arch-linux, dns, networkmanager

I want to use the cloudflare nameserver as a default on my PC, and to achieve that, following the arch wiki, I created this file `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dns-servers.conf` with this contents:

```
[global-dns-domain-*]
servers=2606:4700:4700::1111,1.1.1.1
```

This works, but now I have problems to access some public networks login pages, because they use their automatically provided DNS nameserver to redirect to the login page.

Is there any way to set up networkmanager so that, globally, it uses the nameserver provided by me as a first choice, and the local DHCP nameserver as a fallback?

There is already a [similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/323459/how-to-make-networkmanager-add-a-dns-server-at-the-top-of-etc-resolv-conf), but all the answers are written with the assumption that DNS isn't directly handled by networkmanager, but by dhcpcd or similar software. Is there any way to do this only with networkmanager?

Comment: Hi i have not tried but usually if you add second name server below and it will look for unresolved address by first.I used resolvcof.d and dnsmasq.

Comment: I don't use dnsmasq.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found a way to do it.

First, I deleted `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dns-servers.conf` (if you hadn't created it in the first place, skip this). Then, I created this file `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/pre-up.d/30-add-custom-dns.sh` with this contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$2" = "pre-up" ]; then
    sed -i '1inameserver 1.1.1.1' /etc/resolv.conf
    sed -i '1inameserver 2606:4700:4700::1111' /etc/resolv.conf
fi
```

You have to make sure that it is executable and it belongs to root, I run

`sudo chown root:root /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/pre-up.d/30-add-custom-dns.sh`

and

`sudo chmod +x /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/pre-up.d/30-add-custom-dns.sh`

to be sure. Lastly, I enabled and started this systemd service: `NetworkManager-dispatcher.service`.

This script will run after the initialization of a connection, and will append at the start of `/etc/resolv.conf` an entry for cloudflare nameservers, while still keeping what was already put there by NetworkManager.